# VS Code Output Format

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting

I'm getting my output in VS Code in a single line and its very hectic to drag till very end. How to reformat the VS Code output from single line to multiple lines ?

I was not able to find anything in the settings. Guide me on this.

Comment: without code and terminal output we can only guess

Comment: do you write newline chars to the output

Comment: @starball I'm using jupyter notebook, so not working in terminal. I need the output in multiple lines, and not in single line.